# Asynchronously loading new data to a d3 chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm building a sort of timeline tool using d3.js that can be zoomed and paged forward and back within a set time period. I have my axis transitioning perfectly but I can't seem to get my data to reload. The idea is that the zoom level defines a moving window, for example 1 hour that the user moves backwards and forwards over a period of a few days. Every time they do so a call is made to fetch the data for that hour.

Apologies for the large code block, the methods that handle the fetching of new data are towards the bottom. If it makes any difference the tool is a directive for angular.js.

```
 scope.zoomLevels = [
                {
                    value: 1,
                    unit: 'minutes',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%S')
                },
                {
                    value: 30,
                    unit: 'minutes',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%H:%M')
                },
                {
                    value: 1,
                    unit: 'hours',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%H:%M')
                },
                {
                    value: 3,
                    unit: 'hours',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%H:%M')
                },
                {
                    value: 6,
                    unit: 'hours',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%H:%M')
                },
                {
                    value: 12,
                    unit: 'hours',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%H:%M')
                },
                {
                    value: 1,
                    unit: 'days',
                    tickFormat: $window.d3.time.format('%H:%M')
                }
            ];

            var margin = {top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
                width = $window.innerWidth,
                height = $window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                xAxisHeight = $window.innerHeight - margin.top - ($window.innerHeight/2);

            var start = $window.moment(Datasets.current.dates[0], 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                end = $window.moment(Datasets.current.dates[Datasets.current.dates.length - 1], 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                duration = $window.moment.duration(end.diff(start));

            scope.zoomLevel = 3;
            scope.page = 0;
            scope.maxPage = duration.asMinutes()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value;

            //$scope.tweets = Tweets.getTweets(start.format('x'), end.format('x'));

            var rows = Math.floor(height/ 60);

            console.log(rows + ' Rows');

            var x = $window.d3.time.scale()
                .domain([start.toDate(), start.clone().add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).toDate()])
                .range([0, width]);

            var y =  $window.d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([(rows/2) * -1,(rows/2)])
                .range([height, 0]);

            var xAxis = $window.d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x);

            var yAxis =  $window.d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .tickSize(5)
                .orient('right');

            var svg = $window.d3.select('#timeline').append('svg')
                .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr('height', height)
                .append('g')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'x axis')
                .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + xAxisHeight + ')')
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll('text')
                .attr('y', 15)
                .attr('x', 0)
                .attr('dy', '.35em');

            svg.append('g')
                .attr('class', 'y axis')
                .call(yAxis);

            Articles.get({startDate: start.format(), endDate: start.clone().add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format(), limit: 20}, function(data){

                var bar = svg.selectAll('.news')
                    .data(data.items)
                    .enter()
                    .append('g')
                    .attr('class', 'news')
                    .on('mouseover', function(d) {
                        console.log(d);
                    })
                    .on('mouseout', function(d) {

                    });

                bar.append('rect')
                    .attr('width', 250)
                    .attr('height', 60)
                    .attr('x', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').format('x'));})
                    .attr('y', function(d){return y(2);})

                bar.append('foreignObject')
                    .attr('width', 250)
                    .attr('height', 60)
                    .attr('x', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').format('x'));})
                    .attr('y', function(d){return y(2);})
                    .append('xhtml:p')
                    .attr("class","statement")
                    .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

            });

            scope.movePage = function(direction){
                if(!(direction === 1 && scope.page === scope.maxPage) || !(direction === -1 && scope.page === 0)){

                    console.log('Paging allowed');

                    if(direction === 1){

                        start = start.add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit);

                        x.domain([start.toDate(), start.clone().add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).toDate()]);

                        Articles.get({startDate: start.format(), endDate: start.clone().add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).format(), limit: 20}, function(data) {

                            console.log(data.items.length);

                            svg.selectAll('.news').data(data.items).transition().duration(1500).ease('sin-in-out');

                            svg.selectAll('g.axis.x').transition().duration(1500).ease('sin-in-out').call(xAxis);
                        });

                        scope.page++;
                    }

                    if(direction === -1){

                        start = start.subtract(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit);

                        x.domain([start.toDate(), start.clone().add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).toDate()]);

                        svg.selectAll('g.axis.x').transition().duration(1500).ease('sin-in-out').call(xAxis);

                        scope.page--;

                    }
                }
            };

            scope.toggleZoom = function(direction){
                if(!(direction === 1 && scope.zoomLevel === 6) || !(direction === -1 && scope.zoomLevel === 0)){

                    duration = $window.moment.duration(end.diff(start));

                    scope.zoomLevel = scope.zoomLevel + direction;

                    console.log(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit);

                    switch (scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit){
                        case 'minutes':

                            scope.maxPage = duration.asMinutes()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value;

                            console.log(duration.asMinutes() + ' Minutes');
                            console.log((duration.asMinutes()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value) + ' Pages');
                            break;
                        case 'hours':

                            scope.maxPage = duration.asHours()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value;

                            console.log(duration.asHours() + ' Hours');
                            console.log((duration.asHours()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value) + ' Pages');
                            break;
                        case 'days':

                            scope.maxPage = duration.asDays()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value;

                            console.log(duration.asDays() + ' Days');
                            console.log((duration.asDays()/scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value) + ' Pages');
                            break;
                    }

                    x.domain([start.toDate(), start.clone().add(scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].value, scope.zoomLevels[scope.zoomLevel].unit).toDate()]);

                    svg.selectAll('g.axis').transition().duration(1500).ease('sin-in-out').call(xAxis);

                }
            };
```

Update #1

I've been able to get new data to appear and older data to be removed using the following code in the Articles.get callback after line console.log(data.items.length)

```
var news = svg.selectAll(".news").data(data.items);

                            // Add new element
                            news.enter()
                                .append("g")
                                .attr("class", "news")
                                .transition()
                                .duration(1500)
                                .ease("sin-in-out");

                            news.append('rect')
                                .attr('width', 250)
                                .attr('height', 60)
                                .attr('x', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').format('x'));})
                                .attr('y', function(d){return y(2);});

                            news.append('foreignObject')
                                .attr('width', 250)
                                .attr('height', 60)
                                .attr('x', function(d){return x($window.moment(d.date, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.000Z').format('x'));})
                                .attr('y', function(d){return y(2);})
                                .append('xhtml:p')
                                .attr("class","statement")
                                .text(function(d) { return d.title; });

                            // Remove old elements
                            news.exit()
                                .attr("class", "news")
                                .transition()
                                .duration(1500)
                                .ease("sin-in-out")
                                .remove();
```

However the animations don't really work. Ultimately I want the svg elements that represent each news item to move to the left at the same pace the axis moves if the user clicks next page. Currently they appear/disappear instantly as the user clicks the forward and back buttons.

Comment: So does `console.log(data.items.length);` ever happen? How about `Paging allowed`?

Comment: Yes they both happen. svg.selectAll('g.axis.x').transition().duration(1500).ease('sin-in-out').call(xAxis); happens as well, the axis are redrawn with the new start and end dates on the axis domain

Comment: And `data.items.length` is 20?

Comment: Not always, it can be at most 20. It's pulling international news headlines from a database, each one is timestamped and is plotted on the chart.

Comment: Okay cool, just checking it's more than zero. I guess you have to debug your svg.selectAll('.news') line then.  Maybe add a `$scope.debug = data.items`, then you can put a {{ debug | json }} somewhere in your html and see if anything is wrong with the data from the API

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!(direction === 1 && scope.page === scope.maxPage) || !(direction === -1 && scope.page === 0)){

if(direction === 1){ ... }
if(direction === -1){ .. }
```

This is not easy to parse, are you sure it's possible for either of the inner code blocks to execute given those conditionals?

Comment: Yeah I'm using a variable (direction) to indicate if the user is moving forward or backward in time. 1 moves it forward, -1 move it back. The other logic decides if that is a valid move. For example they're on the first page so can't move back.

Comment: Sorry, yes I got that part. It won't solve your problem, but in that case the the top conditional should be an `&&`. (If they aren't trying to go back before the beginning, and they aren't trying to go forward beyond the end, go ahead and change page)

Comment: So it should! Thanks for the spot